# How to create a Floating window as facebook chatheads with complex Ui on Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, android-mapview

I'll try to go directly to the point.

I am trying to implement a Chathead as facebook do and add a map on the interface.

The Chathead is very easy to implement, even I can use a library for it as http://engineer.recruit-lifestyle.co.jp/techblog/2015-07-29-floatingview/

There are possibly two ways to achieve what I want to do but in both cases I have complications.

The first one is just to use an XML with a LayoutInflater e.g. line 67:
https://github.com/divgunsingh/Floating-Window-Android/blob/master/FloatingWindowExample/src/com/savvy/floatingwindowexample/FloatingWindow.java

But I don't know how to show a map in the interface because Map is a SupportMapFragment.

The second way is to launch an activity from the Chathead service as is explained in this page: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2488094

The problem with the second case is that I can't hide or remove the activity from the stack. I mean, when the user press OnBackPressed I don't want to let the user show the activity again on the Overview button (third button on-screen). Exactly as facebook do.

Resume:

1) Show a Supportmap in the Chathead without Fragments or activities (just in the case if this is the correct way to achieve this kind of things)

2) If I need to use an Activity, how not to show it when Overview button is clicked as Facebook do.

Example in a pic:
[image]

Comment: "But I don't know how to show a map in the interface because Map is a SupportMapFragment" -- then do not use `SupportMapFragment`. Use `MapView`.

Comment: Lol. That's right. @CommonsWare, Facebook messenger does not use activities, does it?

Comment: Chatheads-style floating windows do not use activities, and hence cannot use fragments.

Comment: @CommonsWare, one last question and sorry if a bother you (The obvious will be obviated), Do you know any documentation on good practices to organize the code when working with Chatheads-style ?. I mean, if I have different interfaces to display (e.g. tabs) What would be the correct or more convenient to use to manage it? create a manager per interface or IDK.

Comment: " Do you know any documentation on good practices to organize the code when working with Chatheads-style ?" -- I avoid "chatheads" entirely. I have written software to help users detect when apps have the capability of displaying "chatheads". And, it would not shock me if "chatheads" wind up being broken in some future Android release, as multi-window continues to evolve. I merely wanted to point out that you do not need to use fragments to use maps.